# Can this integral $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos2x}{5+4\cos x}\mathrm dx$ be solved without using complex analysis?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have tried to solve this $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos2x}{5+ 4\cos x}\mathrm dx$ without using complex analysis but with no success. I tried tangent half-angle substitution but it became too complicated. Is there a way?

Comment: Try half-angle substitution, but with a little more determination.

Comment: The $\tan(\theta/2)$ substitution produces a rational function, and any rational function may be integrated in  closed form.  However: if any other method works for such an integral, it is likely to be simpler than the $\tan(\theta/2)$ method.  (Just an anecdotal observation.)

Comment: Another approach is to use the integral formula $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{a+b\cos x} =\frac {\pi} {\sqrt{a^2-b^2}},0<|b|<a$$ which can be established using the substitution $$(a+b\cos x) (a-b\cos t) =a^2-b^2$$

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown You are welcome to show us your solution. Thank you!

Comment: This question feels like a joke that everyone gets but me. (1) Why is this question particularly bad? The OP said they tried the obvious thing but to no avail. Presumably they made a mistake, but so what? That doesn't invalidate the question. (2) Why is there such a fierce edit/close/delete war? The question is 2 months old - let it rest!!!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg [tag:real-analysis], [tag:substitution], and [tag:trigonometry] do not apply here. Knock it off.

Comment: @\Alexander Gruber♦  Integration is located in real analysis. In this topic we say about substitution $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ and most technique here it's trigonometry. I really don't understand you. Also, help me please to open this beautiful topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use
$$\frac{\cos2x}{5+4\cos{x}}=\frac{2\cos^2x-1}{4\cos{x}+5}=\frac{2\cos^2x+\frac{5}{2}\cos{x}-\frac{5}{2}\cos{x}-\frac{25}{8}+\frac{17}{8}}{5+4\cos{x}}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\cos{x}-\frac{5}{8}+\frac{17}{8}\cdot\frac{1}{5+4\cos{x}}.$$
I think, now $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ it's not so complicated.

Comment: Typo. Check the second step. The denominator should have been $4\cos t +5$.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Awesome!!! Can you teach me one thing? How did you manipulate the numerator and divide by the denominator so fast?

Comment: It's just dividing of polynomials: $\frac{2x^2-1}{4x+5}=...$

Comment: For this example that would be a nice way, but in other examples it would be not so nice, the so-called Weierstrass substitution would be able to do this Job.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I got $\displaystyle\int_0^ \infty \frac{2}{9+t^2} dt$ for the last term, It become so easy. Thanks!!

Comment: Sonnhard, we just want before that degree of the nominator will be less than degree of the denominator and the rest it's $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ of course.

Comment: @Simba Yes!!! It gives $\int\frac{2}{9+t^2}dt$ and the rest is easy. You are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

**Hints:**

$$\frac{2\cos^2x-1}{5+4\cos x}=\frac18\left(4\cos x-5+\frac{17}{5+4\cos x}\right).$$

The first terms are easy to deal with.

Now,

$$\frac1{5+4\cos x}=\frac{5-4\cos x}{25-16\cos^2x}=\frac{5-4\cos x}{9+16\sin^2x}=\frac5{9+16\sin^2x}+\frac{4(\sin x)'}{9+16\sin^2x}.$$

You can integrate the second term with a change of variable $t=\sin x$ and that will lead you to an arc tangent.

The remaining term is

$$\frac1{9+16\sin^2x}=\frac{1+\tan^2x}{9+25\tan^2x}=\frac{(\tan x)'}{9+25\tan^2x}$$ and by the change of variable $t=\tan x$, you will also obtain an arc tangent.

Comment: It's nice! But $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ gives the answer immediately.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: the OP found it too complicated.

Comment: I say about the last term: $\frac{1}{5+4\cos{x}}$ Try it and you'll get something very easy.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks!! Your method was also helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Here is simply my way of evaluating this integral. It's not the most straightforward way, but it's the laziest way in my opinion. First, split the integral from zero to $\pi$ and $\pi$ to $2\pi$ and make the substitution $x\mapsto x-\pi$ in the second integral.
$$\begin{align*}\mathfrak{I} & =\int\limits_0^{\pi}\mathrm dx\,\frac {\cos 2x}{5+4\cos x}+\int\limits_0^{\pi}\mathrm dx\,\frac {\cos 2x}{5-4\cos x}\\ & =2\int\limits_0^{\pi}\mathrm dx\,\frac {\cos 2x}{5-4\cos x}\end{align*}$$
Note that in the second line, we've made the substitution $x\mapsto\pi-x$ in the first integral. This intermediate integral is actually rather easy to evaluate. First off is to take note of the infinite sum which can be easily verified by rewriting $\cos nx$ as the real part of $e^{nix}$.
$$\sum\limits_{n\geq0}\frac {\cos nx}{2^{n-1}}=1+\frac 3{5-4\cos x}$$
Now take the general case of the integral above by inserting a parameter $m$ where the two is. Therefore, it follows that
$$\begin{align*}\int\limits_0^{\pi}\mathrm dx\,\frac {\cos mx}{5-4\cos x} & =\frac 23\sum\limits_{n\geq0}2^{-n}\int\limits_0^{\pi}\mathrm dx\,\cos mx\cos nx-\frac 13\int\limits_0^{\pi}\mathrm dx\,\cos mx\end{align*}$$
The second integral evaluates to zero. The first integral is well known and equals
$$\int\limits_0^{\pi}\mathrm dx\,\cos mx\cos nx=\frac {\pi}2\delta_{mn}$$
where $\delta_{mn}=1$ when $m=n$ and $0$ otherwise (I can prove it if you need me to). Take the case $m=2$ and the infinite sum evaluates to zero for every value except when $n=2$ when $\delta_{mn}=1$. Therefore, it's easy to see that
$$\int\limits_0^{\pi}\mathrm dx\,\frac {\cos 2x}{5-4\cos x}=\frac {\pi}{12}$$
Your integral is twice that.
$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\mathrm dx\,\frac {\cos 2x}{5+4\cos x}\color{blue}{=\frac {\pi}6}$$

Answer (score 1):

With $$\cos(t)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$ and $$dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$$ we get the indefinite integral

$$2\int\frac{(t^2+2t-1)(t^2-2t-1)}{(t^2+9)(t^2+1)^2}dt$$ and this is equal
$${\frac {t}{{t}^{2}+1}}-5/4\,\arctan \left( t \right) +{\frac {17\,
\arctan \left( t/3 \right) }{12}}
+C$$

Note that $$\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=t$$

Comment: This is known as the Weierstrass substitution.

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\cos\pars{2x} \over 5 + 4\cos\pars{x}}
\,\dd x} =
\int_{0}^{2\pi}{2\cos^{2}\pars{x} - 1 \over 5 + 4\cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\bracks{-\,{5 \over 8} + {\cos\pars{x} \over 2} +
{17 \over 8}\,{1 \over 5 + 4\cos\pars{x}}}\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{5 \over 4}\,\pi + {17 \over 8}\int_{0}^{2\pi}
{\dd x \over 5 + 4\cos\pars{x}} =
-\,{5 \over 4}\,\pi + {17 \over 8}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}
{\dd x \over 5 - 4\cos\pars{x}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{5 \over 4}\,\pi + {17 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pi}
{\dd x \over 5 - 4\cos\pars{x}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{5 \over 4}\,\pi + {17 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\dd x \over 5 - 4\cos\pars{x}} +
{17 \over 4}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
{\dd x \over 5 - 4\cos\pars{x}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{5 \over 4}\,\pi + {17 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\dd x \over 5 - 4\cos\pars{x}} +
{17 \over 4}\int_{-\pi/2}^{0}
{\dd x \over 5 + 4\cos\pars{x}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{5 \over 4}\,\pi + {17 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\dd x \over 5 - 4\cos\pars{x}} +
{17 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over 5 + 4\cos\pars{x}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{5 \over 4}\,\pi + {85 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\dd x \over 25 - 16\cos^{2}\pars{x}} =
-\,{5 \over 4}\,\pi + {85 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\sec^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x \over 25\sec^{2}\pars{x} - 16} 
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{5 \over 4}\,\pi + {85 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\sec^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x \over 25\tan^{2}\pars{x} + 9} =
-\,{5 \over 4}\,\pi + {85 \over 2}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\,\dd x \over 25x^{2} + 9}}_{\ds{\pi \over 30}}
\\ = &\ \bbx{\pi \over 6} \approx 0.5236 
\end{align}